# Total daily rep does not match reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

[My meta rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d?tab=reputation) for today is `88`:

[image: rep tab]

But the new topbar says `78`.

[image: rep bar]

And the one entry missing in the top bar list that causes the difference is from 5 hours before. So it can't be caching.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does that happen to be cached? _hint hint hint_

Comment: It's like that for a while now. Last upvote was 16 minutes ago

Comment: Caching a notification seems somewhat counter intuitive

Comment: Incidentally I just got some meta rep (woo!) and it came through almost immediately, both the notification and the "+?? today"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll be working on making sure all corner cases are covered by this today.  We expected there would be some differentials once we rolled it into full production load, and I'll be tracking the causes of those down and running some syncs to get things right today.

I have a query batch to see the network vs. per-site differentials, and we'll continue to keep an eye on that until it's rock solid.

Comment: FYI: It is still out of sync currently.

Comment: Now it's in sync again. Could have been caching.

Comment: @juergend I was doing a network sync for this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208361/achievements-box-missed-out-on-upvotes-and-accept/208371#208371 that would have caused delay right when you saw it