# Achievements box missed out on upvotes and accept

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The achievements dropdown box dropped the ball on some votes I received today.

My reputation tab on Stack Overflow shows I gained +169 points so far today:

[image: +169 on Stack Overflow]

The achievements dropdown, on the other hand, claims I only gained +134:

[image: +134 on SO?]

It appears the votes for [*Determine if __getattr__ is method or attribute call*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121035/447356) were entirely missed out; accounting for the 35 point discrepancy. They *should* be listed where I placed a question mark.

Note that the later votes received did not update the achievements tally; the votes were missing before the more recent votes came in already.

**Update**: another vote for the same post showed up as a green `+10` label, but opening the dropdown showed no such vote. I strongly suspect that a specific aspect of that post causes an error somewhere.

Perhaps the double-underscore is interpreted as Markdown and breaks something? Other posts with double-underscores in the title *did* work (yesterday there was one with `__main__.py` in the title), so this is a long shot.

Comment: Maybe the `_` cause this? :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Maybe! That'd be something..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Another vote on the post just got lost, so I think we are on to something here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That said, I got votes on a post with `__main__.py` in the title, they showed up just fine.

Comment: Well, it surely ruins markdown so...

Comment: Did you refresh the page, or are you continually opening the achievements dropdown on the same page?

Comment: @NickCraver: I refreshed the page, and forced a cache clear as well. I am quite aware of the problems faced by keeping a page open. :-P

Comment: I noticed it too, but it used to account for that after a refresh or 2. I did post a comment on the original top-bar beta question posted on meta regarding this. Try giving it a few mins and a couple of refreshes, may be.

Comment: @R.J: It's the fact that a *later* vote showed up as `+10`, then the drop-down showed no trace of the newer vote on that question, that has me thinking this won't resolve in a few refreshes.

Comment: @NickCraver: I note that the [XHR response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements?_=1385041284875) shows no mention of the specific post, or its score.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Actually, it happened with me too, that a later upvote/accept was reflected but a previous reputation increase wasn't. Though it seemed to have self-fixed in a few minutes, we could have a actual bug here, since it hasn't self-fixed for you yet. The double underscores might be the problem.

Comment: Uh, I think you broke SQL.  Hang on, something is definitely off here.

Comment: Ok I see the issue, you deleted and undeleted your post, the rep history is working fine, it's the post aggregation that's not working

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot I did that! My initial read of the question was wrong.

Comment: Dang, I always check revisions but since there was no direct link I was too lazy to [type if manually](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20121035/revisions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** this has now been fixed, the bug was specifically on deleted and undeleted posts.  The aggregation is fixed as is historical data.

---

Fun fact: post undeletions weren't getting aggregated to the network level (where we check against to see if we should display that item in the dropdown).  Funner fact: they *never* aggregated.

Soooooo, I need to fix this and backfill post deletion dates - hang on this will take a while. T-SQL backfills across linked servers? weeeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: Whee, I see the question listed now! :-D Thanks, Nick.

Comment: I just love your writing style, Mr. Craver! :)

Comment: By the way, did it fix other bugs by any chance?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd one other, fixing the JS to clear dropdowns on realtime updates and such now

Comment: Cheers @Nick! :)